What are the equations to calculate the 2RDMs from coupled cluster amplitudes?
A converged CCSD gradient calculation will show the lagrange multipliers (l1 and l2) and excitation amplitudes (t1 and t2). While many codes do not directly give access to the 2RDM, the tensor l2, t2 and the matrices t1 and l1 can be found. This makes me compute the 2RDM (in MO basis) from these arrays.
Are there any equations/ codes that can do that?
UPDATE 1 : I found this algebraic expression for CCD DMs from a lecture by Prof. Gauss. I am confused as is it CCSD DM or not. Also, there are no expressions for VOOO and/or VVVO blocks. Here are the expressions from slide 187,
i,j,k,l = occupied orbital indices and a,b,c,d = unoccupied orbital indices
1PDM:
$$D_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m} \sum_{e,f} \lambda_{ef}^{ij}t_{im}^{ef}$$
$$D_{ab} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m,n} \sum_{e} \lambda_{ae}^{mn}t_{mn}^{be}$$
2RDM:
$$\Gamma_{ijkl}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{e,f}\lambda_{ef}^{kl}t_{ef}^{ij}$$
$$\Gamma_{abcd}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n}\lambda_{ab}^{mn}t_{mn}^{cd}$$
$$\Gamma_{ajib}=\sum_{m,n}\lambda_{ae}^{im}t_{jm}^{be}$$
$$\Gamma_{abij}=\lambda_{ab}^{ij}$$
$$\Gamma_{ijab}=t_{ij}^{ab} + \frac{1}{4} \sum_{m,n}\sum_{e,f} \lambda_{ef}^{mn}t_{ij}^{ef}t_{mn}^{ab} + \frac{1}{2}P_{ij}P_{ab}\sum_{m,n}\sum_{e,f}\lambda_{ef}^{mn}t_{im}^{ae}t_{jm}^{bf} - \frac{1}{2}P_{ab}\sum_{m,n}\sum_{e,f}\lambda_{ef}^{mn}t_{mn}^{eb}t_{ij}^{af} - \frac{1}{2}P_{ij}\sum_{m,n}\sum_{e,f}\lambda_{ef}^{mn}t_{mj}^{ef}t_{in}^{ab}$$
I don't know for sure if $P_{ij}$ are permutations or not.

Let's talk more about this here. I have moved all our comments from here to there!

Sorry, the link in my previous comment only directs us to the chat room, rather than the specific place in the chat room in which the conversation is taking place. Here is where the conversation starts.
